# Override bootstrap styles, disabled state for button class

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Is there any way to set the disabled state color of the bootstrap button class through the http://getbootstrap.com/customize/ page?

I was wondering if it's possible to override the calculated background color and label text color for the button class's disabled state through the aforementioned page just by changing some variables (and then compiling to get the custom css), but I don't know what to do (or what to change) if at all possible.

If it isn't possible through the page, any pointers to help me get to the solution will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Both answers worked (changing @gray-light directly, and creating a style to override the background in a external css file).Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a css file (`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">`) after the bootstrap import and you can override styles at will.

Answer (score 1):

You can customize the various disabled colors background colors and link colors (search for "disabled" and you should find each instance).

By default they use the `@gray-light` color. One way to achieve a wholesale change to all disabled colors would be to change this value in the [Colors](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#colors) section.

If you don't want to change every usage of `@gray-light`, you can change each individual `*-disabled-color`(like `@btn-link-disabled-color`) and `*-bg-disabled` (like `@input-bg-disabled`) value to your liking. You can user their color variables, HEX, or RGB values to define these colors.